# Como chamar uma função apenas 1 vez com scroll do mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu preciso que quando o usuário role o scroll do mouse para cima ou para baixo, seja acionada uma função específica apenas uma única vez...

Estou utilizando o seguinte código mas não está atendendo a minha necessidade:

```
var stopScroll = false;

$(window).scroll(function (event) {   

var scrollAtual = $(this).scrollTop();

if (scrollAtual > lastScrollTop) {      
    // down scroll code     
    if(stopScroll == false){
        console.log('scroll para baixo'); 
        stopScroll = true;

        //depois de 1 segundo ativa a função do scroll down novamente
        setTimeout(function(){              
            stopScroll = false;
        }, 1100);   
    }       
} else {    
    // up scroll code        
    if(stopScroll == false){
        console.log('scroll para cima'); 
        stopScroll = true;

        //depois de 1 segundo ativa a função do scroll up novamente
        setTimeout(function(){              
            stopScroll = false;
        }, 1100);   
    }
}             
lastScrollTop = scrollAtual;         

});
```

Quando eu rolo o scroll para cima ou para baixo, ele chama a função "**console.log()**" inúmeras vezes...preciso que chame apenas 1x e volte a chamar após 1 segundo.

** Eu sei ou meu erro mais ou menos, no começo do código eu declaro a variavel *stopScroll* como false, e dentro do "**$(window).scroll(function (event)**" eu mudo seu valor para true para que ocorra uma parada, mas cada vez que eu rolar o scroll a variavel *stopScroll* voltará a ser false pois irá pegar o valor global.

Preciso de ajuda para arrumar essa lógica, e resolver o meu problema.
Se houver uma maneira mais fácil de fazer isso, gostaria de uma sugestão.

Answer (score 2):

Esse tipo de funções / funcionalidade chama-se *debounce*. Um exemplo poderia ser assim:

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
    var block, self = this;
    return function() {
        if (block) return;
        block = true;
        block = setTimeout(function() {
            block = false;
        });
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

e depois para usar seria:

```
var superFuncao = debounce(1000, function(event){
    // o resto da tua função aqui
});

$(window).scroll(superFuncao);
```

Dá uma olhada a este exemplo e repara como ele corre a função somente uma vez por cada grupo de pedidos: https://jsfiddle.net/1nd8e91k/

Answer (score -2):

Sobre debounce e throttle em JavaScript, recomendo esta lib:

[jquery-throttle-debounce](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce)